# Extended WPF Toolkit - Change button sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am working on a WPF application that uses the Wizard class from the Extended WPF Toolkit. I have the main page set up, but I would like to change the button sizes.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="wizard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:Wizard FinishButtonClosesWindow="True" Next="Wizard_Next" x:Name="Wizard">
            ...
        </xctk:Wizard>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

As you can see at the bottom of the window, there are three buttons. I would like to change the size of them. I've gone through the documentation for Xceed's WPF Toolkit, but I can't find the source code for the buttons anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by *but I can't find the source code for the buttons anywhere* buttons are part of `xctk:Wizard` control ... if there is no style property you can only override default button style for whole Windows to change their size .... or get the soure wpftoolkit and modify

Comment: Sorry, I meant I can't find any documentation for the buttons and how to change their properties. I can only change the events for each one. For example, for the Next button, I can only specify what method to call when it's clicked, but I cannot change the size property.

Comment: ok I've check the source ... you can customize WizardPage but changing Wizard/Themes/Generic.xaml (providing own theme)

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the source and have changed the FontSize property of each of the buttons but it's not applying to my project...

Comment: Nevermind, the correct source code file was Wizard/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml. Thanks for your help!